# UiPath Activity Creator - Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, uipath, rpa, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

So i was been creating activities for uipath from now 5-6 months or so with the old method , manually creating a .netframework project and adding all the input and output arguments for the activity

now as Activity Creator is better way to create custom activity i thought to give it a chance, but i dont know why im unable to publish it , im getting this error

```
|Severity|Code|Description|Project|File|Line|Suppression State|
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
|Error||Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\HP\source\repos\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations.Activities.Design\obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations.Activities.Design_jassvpr0_wpftmp.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig'.|IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations.Activities.Design|C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets|190|
```

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeApkPP8KV8) video |

Here is the code from my side in the Activity

```
 protected override async Task<Action<AsyncCodeActivityContext>> ExecuteAsync(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Inputs
            var timeout = TimeoutMS.Get(context);
            var firstDate = FirstDate.Get(context);
            var secondDate = SecondDate.Get(context);

            // Set a timeout on the execution
            var task = ExecuteWithTimeout(context, cancellationToken);
            if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout, cancellationToken)) != task) throw new TimeoutException(Resources.Timeout_Error);
            int differenceInDays = 0; // Declare outside the try block
            //My Code
            try
            {
                // Check if the dates have the same date component
                if (firstDate.Date == secondDate.Date)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Both dates have the same date component.");
                }
                // Calculate the difference in days
                var timeDifference = secondDate.Date - firstDate.Date;
                 differenceInDays = Math.Abs(timeDifference.Days);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
            // Outputs
            return (ctx) => {
                Output.Set(ctx, differenceInDays.ToString());
            };
        }
```

the only modicfication that i had made is to add a custom icon for the activity [here](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Symbols%20Outlined%3Acalendar_month%3AFILL%401%3Bwght%40400%3BGRAD%400%3Bopsz%4024) was the icon i have used

also when i opend the Designer.XAML i was not able to see any disgn view as there was some error , here are the errors

1 :-

```
 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   XDG0008 The name "ActivityIconConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:UiPath.Shared.Activities.Design.Converters".    IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations.Activities.Design C:\Users\HP\source\repos\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations.Activities.Design\Designers\GetTimeDiffrenceInDaysDesigner.xaml  17
```

2:-

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   XDG-0001    The resource "ActivityIconConverter" has an incompatible type.  IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations.Activities.Design C:\Users\HP\source\repos\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations.Activities.Design\Designers\GetTimeDiffrenceInDaysDesigner.xaml  22
```

3:-

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   XDG0008 The name "ActivityDecoratorControl" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:UiPath.Shared.Activities.Design.Controls".   IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations.Activities.Design C:\Users\HP\source\repos\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations.Activities.Design\Designers\GetTimeDiffrenceInDaysDesigner.xaml  25
```

4:-

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\HP\source\repos\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations.Activities.Design\obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations.Activities.Design_3v41hkt2_wpftmp.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig'.    IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations.Activities.Design C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets   190
```

and here is the Designer.xaml code

```
<sap:ActivityDesigner x:Class="IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations.Activities.Design.Designers.GetTimeDiffrenceInDaysDesigner"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:activity="clr-namespace:IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations.Activities.Properties;assembly=IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations.Activities"
                      xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
                      xmlns:sapv="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.View;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
                      xmlns:sapc="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.Converters;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
                      xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:UiPath.Shared.Activities.Design.Converters"
                      xmlns:uip="clr-namespace:UiPath.Shared.Activities.Design.Controls">

    <sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="..\Themes\Generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <sapc:ArgumentToExpressionConverter x:Key="ArgumentToExpressionConverter" />
            <converters:ActivityIconConverter x:Key="ActivityIconConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>

    <sap:ActivityDesigner.Icon>
        <DrawingBrush Stretch="Uniform" Drawing="{Binding Path=ModelItem, Converter={StaticResource ActivityIconConverter}, ConverterParameter=pack://application:\,\,\,/IndieDev91.DateTimeOperations.Activities.Design;component/themes/icons.xaml}" />
    </sap:ActivityDesigner.Icon>

    <uip:ActivityDecoratorControl Style="{StaticResource ActivityDecoratorStyle}">
        <Grid Width="300">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Content="{x:Static activity:Resources.GetTimeDiffrenceInDays_FirstDate_DisplayName}" Grid.Row="0"
                   ToolTip="{x:Static activity:Resources.GetTimeDiffrenceInDays_FirstDate_Description}"/>
            <sapv:ExpressionTextBox Grid.Row="1" ExpressionType="{Binding ModelItem.Properties[FirstDate].PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0]}" OwnerActivity="{Binding Path=ModelItem}" HintText="{x:Static activity:Resources.GetTimeDiffrenceInDays_FirstDate_Description}" UseLocationExpression="False">
                <sapv:ExpressionTextBox.Expression>
                    <Binding Path="ModelItem.FirstDate" Converter="{StaticResource ArgumentToExpressionConverter}" Mode="TwoWay" ConverterParameter="In" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                </sapv:ExpressionTextBox.Expression>
            </sapv:ExpressionTextBox>

            <Label Content="{x:Static activity:Resources.GetTimeDiffrenceInDays_SecondDate_DisplayName}" Grid.Row="2"
                   ToolTip="{x:Static activity:Resources.GetTimeDiffrenceInDays_SecondDate_Description}"/>
            <sapv:ExpressionTextBox Grid.Row="3" ExpressionType="{Binding ModelItem.Properties[SecondDate].PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0]}" OwnerActivity="{Binding Path=ModelItem}" HintText="{x:Static activity:Resources.GetTimeDiffrenceInDays_SecondDate_Description}" UseLocationExpression="False">
                <sapv:ExpressionTextBox.Expression>
                    <Binding Path="ModelItem.SecondDate" Converter="{StaticResource ArgumentToExpressionConverter}" Mode="TwoWay" ConverterParameter="In" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                </sapv:ExpressionTextBox.Expression>
            </sapv:ExpressionTextBox>
        </Grid>
    </uip:ActivityDecoratorControl>
</sap:ActivityDesigner>
```